# using Java Generics with a specific type

Tags: java, generics

I'm working on some LeetCode practice with binary search trees. I'm wondering if someone might explain the following method signature:

```
 public List<List<Integer>> levelOrder(TreeNode root) {
```

I am confused by the use of Java Generics here -- what exactly `List<List<Integer>>` is saying in this case.

I understand Java Generics to be a way to "The <...> syntax allows you to write generic classes and methods that can handle multiple different types" according to https://programming.guide/java/less-than-greater-than-syntax.html

and I've seen it with  with ArrayLists, but what does this specific definition of an integer list mean here?

Thanks

Comment: It's a list of integer lists

Comment: `List<List<Integer>>` can be parsed `List<A>` where `A` is `List<Integer>`. So what you have is a list containing lists of integers.

Comment: @littlebenlittle and Joelius Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<List<Integer>>` should be read as "a list of list of integers".

If you were defining "a list of list of integers" in pseudo-code it might look like this:

```
[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [], [ 4, 5 ], [] ]
```

An `ArrayList` is a kind of `List`. Every `ArrayList` is a `List`, but not every `List` is an `ArrayList`.

The reason Java does this is because you (usually) do not want your code to depend on a specific implementation of a list, but rather the [contract of a list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead.